# Relation of not solvable indefinite Integrals to the Galois theory?

Tags: galois-theory, indefinite-integrals

Is there any simple explanation around why the following indefinite integral has not any solution? Is it related to the Galois theory? If yes, How?
$$
\int\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} dx = Li_2(e^{-x})+x\log(e^x+1) + c
$$

Comment: It should be: $$
\int\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} dx = Ln(e^x+1) + c
$$

Answer (score 2):

There are algebraic explanations for the nonexistence of elementary indefinite integrals. See [How can you prove that a function has no closed form integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)

There is also a Galois theory of differential equations, which includes indefinite integration. It is called [Differential Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory).

For a recent book, see [Lectures on Differential Galois Theory](http://www.ams.org/cgi-bin/bookstore/bookpromo?fn=20&arg1=ulectseries&item=ULECT-7) by Magid.